# Adding two tensors in different coordinate systems

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, post-newtonian

I have difficulties understanding the following (Everything out of the book Gravity by Poisson and Clifford): We have a quantity $\mathfrak{g}^{\alpha \beta}$ called gothic inverse metric in prior unspecified coordinates. Then we impose the four harmonic coordinate conditions $\partial_{\beta}\mathfrak{g}^{\alpha \beta}=0$. So far so good. Now they define the potentials $$ h^{\alpha \beta} := \eta^{\alpha \beta} - \mathfrak{g}^{\alpha \beta} \,,$$
where $\eta^{\alpha \beta}:= diag(−1, 1, 1, 1)$ is the Minkowski metric expressed in Lorentzian coordinates. I don't understand in what coordinates the quantity $h^{\alpha \beta}$ is written now. Maybe this is a stupid question and I just don't understand it, but what does it even mean do add the fields $\eta$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ when they are written in different sets of coordinates.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did the book say that $\eta^{\alpha\beta}$ is defined in a different coordinate system than $g^{\alpha\beta}$? Mathematically, nothing is wrong with adding two different tensors as long as they're written the same coordinate system. We can even have two different *metric* tensors in the same coordinate system, and then adding (or subtracting) them gives another valid tensor, but it generally won't be another *metric* tensor.

Comment: The quantity $\mathfrak{g}$ isn't even a tensor, rather a tensor density I think. However, its components are expressed in some coordinates that are fixed via the harmonic conditions. So how would I able to know if the Minkowski metric would take the given standard form in that set of coordinates? The book just states that the Minkowski metric is given in "Lorentzian coordinates".

Comment: Physicists are often sloppy with language -- which stinks, because we need language to communicate ideas. I recommend ignoring the book's language about "Lorentzian coordinates" and focusing on the mathematical basics: given a smooth manifold, we can define tensor fields on it. Let's say that $\eta^{ab}$ and $g^{ab}$ are two tensor fields defined on the manifold. This by itself means that $\eta^{ab}-g^{ab}$ is also a perfectly well-defined tensor field. It is understood that they're both written in the same coordinate system, but that coordinate system is arbitrary.  (continued...)

Comment: Now suppose that $\eta^{ab}$ and $g^{ab}$ both happens to have all the properties required of a metric field. Their difference is *still* a good tensor field (endowing them with extra properties doesn't change that basic fact), even though the difference may not qualify as a *metric* field. Okay, now impose the conditions $\partial_b g^{ab}=0$ and $\eta^{ab}=diag(-1,1,1,1)$. We can impose both of those conditions in the same coordinate system. (Changing the coordinate system would make them both look different, of course.) continued...

Comment: I wonder if the confusing is coming from the author's insistence on *naming* the coordinate system. It's a single coordinate system in which the conditions   $\partial_b g^{ab}=0$ and $\eta^{ab}=diag(-1,1,1,1)$ are both satisfied. What should we call it? Doesn't matter, as long as we *define* it -- which we already did.